# How to make a task in pipeline block till the collection is full before removing items from it

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have 3 tasks which form a pipeline. I want the finalizer task (last in the pipeline) to start consuming data from buffer2 only after it reached it's bounder capacity. Right now, it picks each item as they arrive and I dont want that.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> input = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).ToList();

        BlockingCollection<int> buffer1 = new BlockingCollection<int>(10);
        BlockingCollection<int> buffer2 = new BlockingCollection<int>(5);

        Task producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Producer(input, buffer1));
        Task consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consumer(buffer1, buffer2));
        Task finalizer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Finalizer(buffer2));

        Task.WaitAll(producer,consumer, finalizer);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Producer(List<int> input, BlockingCollection<int> buffer1)
    {
        foreach (int i in input)
        {
            buffer1.Add(i);
        }

        buffer1.CompleteAdding();
    }

    private static void Consumer(BlockingCollection<int> buffer1, BlockingCollection<int> buffer2)
    {
        foreach(int i in buffer1.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer saw item " + i);

            buffer2.Add(i);
        }

        buffer2.CompleteAdding();
    }

    private static void Finalizer(BlockingCollection<int> buffer)
    {
        foreach (int i in buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // Do some work
            Console.WriteLine("Finalizer saw item " + i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        buffer.CompleteAdding();
    }
```

How can I make finalizer stop from consuming the items from buffer2 before it has 5 items in it?. Also same for consumer, it should start consuming only when buffer 1 has at least 10 items.

Comment: Just curious. Do you have a legitimate use case where this behavior is useful?

Comment: Yes. I have a huge csv file on disk. I want to read a chunk of lines and then process those lines before in consumer sending it to finalizer which sends those lines to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at [TPL Dataflow from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have made some changes to your code to accomodate TPL

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> input = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).ToList();

    BatchBlock<int> buffer1 = new BatchBlock<int>(10);
    BatchBlock<int> buffer2 = new BatchBlock<int>(5);
    ActionBlock<int[]> action1;
    ActionBlock<int[]> action2;

    action1 = new ActionBlock<int[]>(t => { Consumer(t, buffer2); },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });

    buffer1.LinkTo(action1, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    action2 = new ActionBlock<int[]>(t => Finalizer(t),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });

    buffer2.LinkTo(action2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    Task produceTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Producer(input, buffer1));

    Task.WaitAll(produceTask);
    action1.Completion.Wait();//Will add all the items to buffer2
    buffer2.Complete();//will not get any new items
    action2.Completion.Wait();//Process the batch of 5 and then complete
    Console.WriteLine("Process complete");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void Finalizer(int[] t)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received a batch of items {0}", t.Count());
    foreach (int i in t)
    {
        // Do some work
        Console.WriteLine("Finalizer saw item " + i);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private static void Consumer(int[] t, BatchBlock<int> buffer2)
{
    foreach (var item in t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consumer saw item " + item);
        buffer2.Post(item);
    }

}

public static void Producer(List<int> input, BatchBlock<int> buffer1)
{
    foreach (int i in input)
    {
        buffer1.Post(i);
    }

    //Once marked complete your entire data flow will signal a stop for
    // all new items
    buffer1.Complete();

}
```

[Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/4.5.24) is the nuget package which I used

**EDIT** Updated the above code to take the min count of 10 while consuming.  As to your doubt if it will fit the bill when we have skewed distribution then the answer is *YES*

Comment: Thank you . I forgot to mention that the consumer should also block till at least 10 items are present in the buffer1. I have updated the Q.

Comment: Then instead of using `BufferBlock` use BatchBlock` and then you should be done

Comment: Will this also work in the case, when I have say 22 lines which won't partition equally into 10 piece blocks and 5 piece blocks?

Comment: Also an interesting point to be observed is that you make this process execute in parallel just by increasing the value of `MaxDegreeofParallelism` property. Be careful while doing it as it will increase the load on CPU. You have to strike a balance between parallel processing and hardware.

Comment: Isn't that the max no if outstanding tasks should be no of processors on the system/2?

Comment: No. Each processor core has many (say 25) threads available. So for a quad core processor it would be four times the threads per core(100 threads in this example). The `MaxDegreeofParallelism` is for total threads and not processor cores

Comment: I see. There should be a way to dynamically determine how many tasks to spin up at run time by querying a system api for optimum performance. Isn't there ?

Comment: There are some but way too complex as you have to strike a balance between performance and also memory utilization. I generally suggest trial and error approach.

Comment: What about using a thread pool instead of trying to create your own threads and managing them ? Won't it be better to let the system decide how many optimum threads should be created instead of trial and error

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered but just want to show another way of doing this by implementing own version of GetConsumingEnumerable. You call this method instead of BlockingCollection method by passing the collection as a parameter:

```
    private IEnumerable<T> GetConsumingEnumerable<T>(BlockingCollection<T> sourceCollection)
    {
        var buffer = new List<T>();

        foreach (var item in sourceCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            buffer.Add(item);

            if (buffer.Count >= sourceCollection.BoundedCapacity)
            {
                foreach (var bItem in buffer)
                {
                    yield return bItem;
                }

                buffer.Clear();
            }
        }

        foreach (var bItem in buffer)
        {
            yield return bItem;
        }
    }
```